# How to view properties of an open serial connection?

Tags: windows, serial-port

How can I view which properties an open serial connection has?
So the baud, start and stop bits, the parity, the number of data bits and especially how the to be transmitted string is terminated (line feed, and so on)

Or is there a windows-tool for?

Comment: in what windows? or

Comment: Oh sorry, I've forgotten. I need a solution for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't very clear from the question but I have to assume that some other program is using the port.  Which stops you from opening the port, required to get the settings.  Serial ports cannot be shared.  You can do so after the program closes the port, but there are non-zero odds that it restores the settings.

The best way is to use the free SysInternals' [Portmon utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx).  It installs a filter driver that snoops on the serial port driver.  You'll see everything the program does, including initializing the port.

Comment: Yes an other program is using the port and I've to know the settings. Portmon Utiltiy looks very good, do you know if there a 64-Bit-Version?

Comment: Sadly there is not, I have done this search my self and I could not find any free tool that has a 64 bit driver. What I ended up doing is forwarding the serial port to a VM running a 32 bit windows and running my program and PortMon inside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for this and connect with PuTTY to the serial port and set the baud rate, start and stop bits and such with PuTTY when you connect to the serial port of a device using PuTTY.

Comment: Not really. I've to know the port-settings an other software is using.

Comment: Doesn't PuTTY fail if another program is already using the serial port in question? And doesn't PuTTY try to force its own settings otherwise?